# connect app on Django to the existing modx revo web site

Tags: django, modx

is it possible to connect the app written on Django to the existing MODX Revo web site?
The Django app should use data from MODX Revo database, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use MODX API, here is the [reference](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extending-modx/api-reference)

Comment: what if I try to connect directly? is there any restrictions?

Comment: @apet yes direct connection is possible, but API is more proper way from architecture and security point of view.